# Printing the PHP file name which calls a jQuery's post method

Tags: php, jquery

I have a file named as index.php. It has jQuery code which executes the file test.php.

Here is the code of the file index.php:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery.post("test.php", {
    kaavio: kaavio
  }).done(function(data) {
    $('#valvonta').html(data);
  });
});
```

The file test.php has this row:

```
<?php echo basename($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>
```

The file test.php should print the current file name (index.php), not test.php. Anyway, it will print test.php insteaad of index.php.

How could I solve my problem?

Comment: It's working as you would expect. Why don't you just put `echo basename($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);` in index.php?

Comment: because the script is running on `test.php`

Comment: You cannot do that, since the code is placed in the test.php file. Why do you want it to print index.php?

Comment: I haven't tested this, but you could try `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];` in test.php

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do, but this might help you. javascript document.URL https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_url.asp then you can extract filename from it

Comment: If you want to pass the current filename(index.php) to the test.php , then you need&use ajax

Comment: You need to tell us what you're wanting to do here - at least respond to comments.

Comment: @JayBlanchard It seems to me that `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];` did help this time.

Answer (score -1):

Interesting, I tested your code on my computer and can get the correct result. Can you please check your code?

index.php

```
<html><script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.js"
  integrity="sha256-wPFJNIFlVY49B+CuAIrDr932XSb6Jk3J1M22M3E2ylQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="valvonta">valvonta</div>
<script>
$(function(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery.post("test.php", {
        kaavio: 'abc'
      }).done(function(data) {
        $('#valvonta').html(data);
      });
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

test.php

```
<?php echo basename($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>
```

Comment: Please do not use answers to ask clarification questions. [It's not hard to earn enough rep to make comments.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Comment: Thanks for your reminder, my apologies that I had not seen your answer when I was trying his code...